# Positioning text over image (html,css)

Tags: html, css, centering

So, I have an image and I want to display in the center of it some text.

**Code:**

```
.img {
    position: relative;
}

.img h3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%
    top: 85px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ok, so I managed to do it. But here is the thing: when I resize my browser and the image becomes smaller, the text is going out of the image.

So my question is, do I have to use the `@media` rule for all the different dimensions? And how do I know which dimensions to use in my CSS?

Or is there maybe something I can do so my text element always stays inside the image?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a `%` unit for `top`. If you want more specific help, give us a [mcve] of what you have so far so we can see the issue.

Comment: can you show your html

Comment: Thank you ! adding % instead of pixels worked for the height problem. I also have a problem with the text alignment and i was wondering if the text-align:center; is not correct? 

Here is the html
`<div class="homeimg1">

<img src="http://localhost/ks/wp-content/uploads/1.jpg" alt="" width="355" height="245" />
<h3>SET UP</h3>
</div>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a bunch of different options you can make use of, each with its pros & cons and with a difference in browser support:

### **1. Flexbox:** *([support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox))*

Flexbox is the simplest option you have, without using tables or having to get your elements out of the document flow, but it's not as widely supported as other viable options. I trust it will be soon enough.

**Code:**

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
.background {
    height: 10em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background > h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div class = "background" style = "background-image: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HD-Vintage-Photography-Wallpaper.jpg);">
  <h4>Hello, world!</h4>
</div>
```

### **2. Line-height:** *([support](http://caniuse.com/#search=line-height))*

When using this option, you have to ensure that:

- the line height of the title is **equal** to the container's height and
- the title is an one-liner.

<sub>*(view note #2)*</sub>

**Code:**

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
.background {
    height: 10em;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background > h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 5em; /* container height / 2 */
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div class = "background" style = "background-image: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HD-Vintage-Photography-Wallpaper.jpg);">
  <h4>Hello, world!</h4>
</div>
```

### **3. Position: Absolute & Transform:** *([support](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform))*

This is probably the overall most used method as it is widely enough supported, but it has the disadvantage that gets the element *(title)* off the normal flow.

**Code:**

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
.background {
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background > h4 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div class = "background" style = "background-image: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HD-Vintage-Photography-Wallpaper.jpg);">
  <h4>Hello, world!</h4>
</div>
```

### **4. Table** *([support](http://caniuse.com/#search=table))*

Well, I will likely be lynched, if anybody finds this out, but you can use **`display: table`** for the container and **`display: table-cell`** for the title to take advantage of the aligning of tables.

You can now center your title:

- horizontally, by using **`text-align: center`** and
- vertically, by using **`vertical-align: middle`**

**Code:**

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
.background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    display: table;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background > h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div class = "background" style = "background-image: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HD-Vintage-Photography-Wallpaper.jpg);">
  <h4>Hello, world!</h4>
</div>
```

---

### **Notes:**

1. Since we are using an empty **`div`** for our image the **`height`** must be explicitly defined at all times.
2. Using `line-height` to center an element vertically requires that the `line-height` is **equal** to the height of the parent. In this case, **`50%` of the parent height** is used, due to the fact that the `font-size` of the title is `2x` the `font-size` of the parent and its also expressed in `ems`.
3. With regard to the **`@media`** query you made mention of, it should not be used for simple stuff like centering text, but rather for showing/hiding elements based on screen size etc.
4. If you care about the portability of your website to smaller screens, my advice is to avoid using **`px`** *(pixels)*, but instead use **`%`** *(percentages)* that will update based on the screen or **`em`** *(ems)* by manually updating the **`font-size`** of the container using a **`@media`** query.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and your advice!

The second and third methods worked great! I will try the other two as well.

In the line height method, i don't understand why the line-height of the title must be %50 off the container height. For me the title is centered by using 16em; height for the container and 10em; for the line-height.

Comment: It's just a hack that works most of the time. I suspect the issue you see is due to some **`margin`** or **`padding`** of the title or the container. I'd go with one of the other three if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `top: 50%;`, `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

Really common trick these days with excellent browser support. Important to note, you need to specify some sort of height for `.img` for the inner element to be positioned properly. In this example, I used a `vh` unit for height to show how responsive it really is. Resize away.

I also prefer to use a background-image for things like this because it makes the markup so much easier. You're either going to want to use `background-image` or include the `<img>` tag inside `div.img`.

```css
.img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    background: #ccc;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474693220100-7cddec4346f6?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.img h3 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <h3>Hello, world!</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse !
By using this code, although the text stays static while i resize, i dont have my text aligned in the center.If i put text-align:center it will be centered but again, if i resize the window, it will go off.
[link]http://prntscr.com/ed1nvy

Comment: @AlexMpatzios might be because the `h3` had `width: 100%;` on it. Try taking that out, as my example didn't have it.

Comment: Running the code snippet it is centered correctly until text split over two lines with a smaller window. Then the text is too much to the left. Still this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use media query for centering text each time you resize the screen. The solution below will work.

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="" >
  <div class="center">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* --- CSS --- */
.background {
    height: 10em;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.background > h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: none;
}
 .background:hover {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--- HTML --->
<div class = "background" style = "background-image: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/HD-Vintage-Photography-Wallpaper.jpg);">
  <h4>Hello, world!</h4>
</div>
```