# Two background images side by side with text inside of them

Tags: html, css

I trying to have two images side by side as background with some text. As soonest i start positioning text whole browser start expanding to right. I would like to manipulate only with text to positioned. Thank you for help.

```css
.container1{
  background-image: url(pictures/1.png),url(pictures/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-position: left 0px,right 0px;
  background-size: 50% auto,50% auto;
}

.cityText{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"> 
  <div class="cityText">
    <q>
      Life is what happens <br>
      when you’re busy<br>
      making other plans.</q>
      <p>-John Lennon-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="beautyText">
    <q>
    People are like stained - glass windows.<br>
    They sparkle and shine when the sun is out,<br>
    but when the darkness sets in, their true beauty<br>
    is only if there is a light from within.
    </q>
    <p>-Elisabeth Kubler-Ross-</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Does adding `position: absolute;` to the `cityText` solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning text over image (html,css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450098/positioning-text-over-image-html-css)

Comment: Yes it did. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the attached code in which I have added `position:absolute;` to `.cityText` and `position:relative;` to `.container1`. It will sure solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to assist you.

I have a suggestion for you that use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` or `%` because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

```css
.container1{
  background-image: url(pictures/1.png),url(pictures/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-position: left 0px,right 0px;
  background-size: 50% auto,50% auto;
  position: relative;
}

.cityText{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container1"> 
  <div class="cityText">
    <q>
      Life is what happens <br>
      when you’re busy<br>
      making other plans.</q>
      <p>-John Lennon-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="beautyText">
    <q>
    People are like stained - glass windows.<br>
    They sparkle and shine when the sun is out,<br>
    but when the darkness sets in, their true beauty<br>
    is only if there is a light from within.
    </q>
    <p>-Elisabeth Kubler-Ross-</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much that helped to fix that problem. now i can see second background img. is not the same as first one missing very thin line on bottom. if you can, do you know to make sure text  will stay in the same position when i resize browser and not move but shrink with browser size. thank you again

Comment: @Tommy for making text responsive(i.e. when you resize your browser it should stay at same position) use `vw` for text also instead of `px`. If it doesn't work let me know and sorry for late reply.

Comment: i made as you suggested but when i resize browser img. shrink and leave big empty space on right. also i was trying to make my element stay in the same size, in the same position (without shrinking), when i resize browser and just get scroll bar on right/bottom   but still no success. also in container1  when i replace width % for vw after i resize browser img. shrink and leave empty space on right. that fine you could not reply right away i'm so happy for your help. thank you

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue and whether you liked my suggestion or do I need to ameliorate my skills and suggestion? Because I read the comments on your post and it seems your issue is solved but if not please let me know.

Comment: Hi, no i still have problem with that, because i don't want to have that empty space when my browser resize. basically i would like to have the same like when u resize this website all elements move nice and they stay neat. And can you pls tell me when i changed  % for vw when resize browser i have empty space on right.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container1{
  background-image: url(pictures/1.png),url(pictures/2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-position: left 0px,right 0px;
  background-size: 50% auto,50% auto;
  position:relative;
}

.cityText{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"> 
  <div class="cityText">
    <q>
      Life is what happens <br>
      when you’re busy<br>
      making other plans.</q>
      <p>-John Lennon-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="beautyText">
    <q>
    People are like stained - glass windows.<br>
    They sparkle and shine when the sun is out,<br>
    but when the darkness sets in, their true beauty<br>
    is only if there is a light from within.
    </q>
    <p>-Elisabeth Kubler-Ross-</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

please add `position:absolute;` to **cityText** and also add **position:relative;** to **container1** class