# How to write text over an image?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to write a text over an image and i want it to be centered over the image
this is the HTML code:

```
<div class="cloud d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class=" col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <img  src="./img/CloudB.png" class="img-fluid ">
        <p id="exp">EXPLORE YOUR LANGUAGE </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need to absolute position the `p` tag and set their `top` and `left` properties with CSS

Comment: Do you need text above the image, or on the image?

Comment: I am not fluent in Bootstrap, but if you can make that image be a background of the containing div using `background-image`, then you can center the text using plain flexbox (as you do with the top level div).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positioning text over image (html,css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450098/positioning-text-over-image-html-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div class='clueless'>
        <img  src="./img/CloudB.png" class="img-fluid ">
        <p id="exp">EXPLORE YOUR LANGUAGE </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

in css::

```
.clueless{
  position:relative;
}

img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#exp{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

you are good to go.i avoided unimportant inline attr.

Answer (score 0):

short message
use `position:relative;` on image and use `position:absolute;` and direction like `left` or `right` or you can use `transform` for image .